# Asyncio threadsafe primitives

Tags: multithreading, locking, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I need Threadsafe primitives (locking, conditions Semaphore), do they exist in the asyncio ecosystem?

I created some code myself, but it feels a bit sluggish:

```
import asyncio
from threading import get_ident,Lock,Event

class AsyncThreadsafeEvent():
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(AsyncThreadsafeEvent, self).__init__()
        self.waiters = {}
        self.event = Event()

    def set(self):
        self.event.set()
        events = self.waiters.values()
        for loop,event in events:
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(event.set)


    async def wait(self):
        event = asyncio.Event()
        #not strictly necessary but could provide tiny speedup
        if self.event.is_set():
            return

        self.waiters[get_ident()] = (asyncio.get_event_loop(),event)

        #to ensure thread safty
        if self.event.is_set():
            return

        await event.wait()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please describe your use case for this kind of thread-safe asyncio primitive? The event loop is normally single **and** single-threaded, optionally connecting to multi-threaded code using tools like `run_in_executor` and `run_coroutine_threadsafe`. Why do you need multi-threaded code awaited by multiple event loops, as opposed to multiple coroutines within a single event loop?

Comment: I'm using django channels. As Django is Multithreaded, for my usecase I need to add synchronization across multiple threads.

Comment: Why not run a single event loop in a dedicated thread, and talk to it using `call_soon_threadsafe` and `run_coroutine_threadsafe`? Then you could use asyncio primitives like `asyncio.Event`, which you would set using `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(event.set)`, and await in the usual way.